# Зпретить индексацию сайта - robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Как запретить индексацию сайта, поисковыми ботами с такой ссылкой

site.ru/post-gigant-3.html?ordering=date_pub&orderto=asc

Где присутствует такое

?ordering=date_pub&orderto=asc

поисковик не индексировал, чтобы для индексации разрешался в таком виде

site.ru/post-gigant-3.html

Answer (score 3):

Запретите все ненужные урлы:

```
//Запретить урлы содержащие ordering= в урл
Disallow: *ordering=*

//Запретить урлы содержащие orderto= в урл
Disallow: *orderto=*
```

Ну и так далее

Answer (score 1):

Используй конструкцию:

```
Disallow: /*?ordering=*&orderto=*
```

или

```
Disallow: /*.html?ordering=*&orderto=*
```